# My Android App keeps on crashing when running using Android Studio's Emulator

Tags: runtime-error

The project doesn't have any error during synchronization of gradle and the building of the project. Even when I have clean the project, and rebuild the project. The error comes out during running the application in the android studio's emulator. The app keeps crashing.

The error shown:
Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com.example.nfctagrfidopigpio
Could not find apks for this package: com.example.nfctagrfidopigpio

It still shows the same error after I build the APK of the project. I don't know what else to do.
Do help me

For the error package user, I have added 3 module inside the project itself. So, the question is, should I change the package name of the imported module to get the same module name as appeared in the error above?

This is my build.gradle file:

## \

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    //id 'com.android.library'
    id 'maven-publish'

}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    // Define the release property
    ext {
        release = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nfctagrfidopigpio"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 33
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments = [
                'rfc2217_server_host': '192.168.0.144',
                'rfc2217_server_nonstandard_baudrates': 'true'
        ]
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'com.example.nfctagrfidopigpio'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    /*implementation(project(':usbSerialForAndroid')) {
        exclude module: 'BuildConfig'
    }*/
     //implementation 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: have settled all the problems faced